# Replace text with html or css on underlying platform

Tags: html, css

I'm working on customizing an online app that has an underlying platform, so I'm a bit limited on how much of the structure I can change. They do offer full CSS customization and HTML customization for the head.

There are instances on the app that say "1 Point" `.cost` that I would like to change to "1 Referral." Is it possible to do this given the limited capabilities? I cannot edit the html directly. Is it possible to replace it in some way?

Comment: Can you add JavaScript?

Comment: I can't add JavaScript unfortunately.

Comment: Really? not even adding a `<script>` tag in the head?

Comment: I could definitely give it a try @remdevtec - It says that you're only allowed to use link and style tags

Comment: I posted an answer, however, I would be able to assist you better if you could post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in CSS. Here you go. See the JSfiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanmpower/8dw3w3rg/)

HTML:

```
<div class="demo"> 
    <span> 1 Point </span> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.demo span{
display:none;
}

.demo:after{
content: "1 Referral";   
}
```

Comment: No problem!! Happy to help. Although I do have a word of advice, if i were you, i'd still post the relevant code into your question to reduce the chances that your question is flagged for being "Too Broad". And that's not good for anyone. Not you, or the community :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in the head, or the body, or wherever you can:

```
<script>
  document.body.addEventListener("load", function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/1 Point/g, '1 Referral');}
, false);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Gave it a go, but it erased the code after I saved it.